# How can I set one column in a table where a column in another table has a certain value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one contains a lot of product information such as product_name product_id etc and the other contains a list of product_ids and where or not that product is marked as on sale. I would like to be able to create something that I can run regularly through a Chron job which will look at table1.product_discount_id and if the product has anything in that column other than 0 it will update table2.product_on_sale to yes. I am having trouble with understanding how to make sure that I only alter the fields for the products with a discount id of anything other than 0. I have got this far in the php script:

```
mysql_connect("myhost", "mydb", "mypassword") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product WHERE product_discount_id != '0'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo $row['product_id'];
  echo ",";
  }
```

and that will produce a list of the product_ids for the products I wish to change the table2.product_on_sale field to yes. I'd like to then say if the product ids previously retrieved match a product_id in table2.product_on_sale field then change to yes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Ali.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("update table1, table2 set table2.product_on_sale=true where table1.product_id=table2.product_id and table1.product_discount_id!=0")
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me an enormous amount!

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be updating with a cron job but using a join in the select to find what's on sale

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you could give me an example of how this would work I would be very grateful. Regards, Ali.